# Inline styling in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

I know this is a basic question and have asked several times. I read most of the questions and answers related to inline styling in Reactjs. But couldn't find what I was searching for or I couldn't understand what they have said as I am new to Reactjs.

I know inline styling can be implemented as an object like below.

`<div className="card" style={{ width: 250, height: 50 }}>My card</div>`

I am just curious how can I add a box-shadow with various values using the inline styling like above.

example
`boxShadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0px 1px 3px 0px, rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.15) 0px 0px 0px 1px;`

I know I can use a separate CSS file, but I just want to add only this box-shadow to a pre-defined bootstrap card.

I searched but couldn't find a proper answer. Just want to know if this is possible and if so a method to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just quote them.

```
<div style={{ 
  boxShadow: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0px 1px 3px 0px, rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.15) 0px 0px 0px 1px" 
}} >My card</div>
```